# Argument of type 'E' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ [s: string]: unknown; } | ArrayLike<unknown>'?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Trying to upgrade [a library](https://github.com/fireflysemantics/collections/blob/master/src/index.ts#L214) that uses this function to the latest version of Typescript:

```
/**
 * For each instance of type `E` in the array argument
 * map the property values into arrays keyed by the name of the 
 * property in the instance of type `E`.
 * @param entities The array of entities
 * @return A single object with all the property values on the entities mapped into arrays.
 *
 * 
 * @example
students:Student[] = [
    {id:1, name:'1', sex:'X', standard: 1, propName: 11, anotherSillyPropName:111,},
    {id:2, name:'2', sex:'Y', standard: 2, propName: 22, anotherSillyPropName:222,},
    {id:3, name:'3', sex:'Z', standard: 3, propName: 33, anotherSillyPropName:333,},
]

console.log(toArrayByObjectKey(students))
* 
* CREDIT:
* Implementation provided by Georg per this SO answer:
* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55404204/attempting-to-understand-reduce-functions-for-object-mapping
*/
export function toArrayByObjectKey<E>(entities:E[]) {

    let res:any = {};

    for (let obj of entities)
        for (let [k, v] of Object.entries(obj))
            res[k] = (res[k] || []).concat(v)

    return res;
};
```

It used to compile fine, but now now it's getting this error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(o: { [s: string]: unknown; } | ArrayLike<unknown>): [string, unknown][]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'E' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ [s: string]: unknown; } | ArrayLike<unknown>'.
      Type 'E' is not assignable to type 'ArrayLike<unknown>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(o: {}): [string, any][]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'E' is not assignable to parameter of type '{}'.ts(2769)
index.ts(237, 36): This type parameter might need an `extends ArrayLike<unknown>` constraint.
index.ts(237, 36): This type parameter might need an `extends { [s: string]: unknown; } | ArrayLike<unknown>` constraint.
```

So I tried both of the suggestions, however that leads to this type of error when running the tests.

```
Error: projects/fs-collections/src/lib/src/index.spec.ts:154:41 - error TS2344: Type 'Student' does not satisfy the constraint '{ [s: string]: unknown; } | ArrayLike<unknown>'.
  Type 'Student' is not assignable to type '{ [s: string]: unknown; }'.
    Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'Student'.

154     let s:Students = toArrayByObjectKey<Student>(students);
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Use `E extends {}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What TS is trying to tell you is that he cannot understand what type `E` should be

Specifying that `E extends object` TS knows that E surely will be an `object`

try using

```js
export function  toArrayByObjectKey<E extends object>(entities:E[]) {
...
}
```

as signature